# Getting the html of a dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page where a plugin adds child div's to a parent div at random time interval.
The basic structure is :

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="child" someattr="abc">content1</div>
<div class="child" someattr="xyz">content2</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following to detect adding of elements and it works

```
var c = document.getElementById('parent');
c.__appendChild = c.appendChild;
c.appendChild = function(){
     alert("Added");
     c.__appendChild.apply(c, arguments);     
}
```

I got the above from an answer in stackoverflow itself.
What I would also like to do is to get the contents of the child divs.
That is, their attributes and the content inside.
What would be the easiest/best way to go on this.
I wouldn't mind if the solution is jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery needed:

```
document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML;
```

Of course you could use jQuery as well, because it might help you get the individual children:

```
$('#parent .child').each(
    function(){ 
         // In this context, 'this' points to the current child element in the itertion
    }
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to select the last child using jquery?

Comment: Yes: `$('#parent .child').last()` or `$('#parent .child:last')`. But this is info you can easily find. If you google for 'jQuery last element' it's the first hit. jQuery is pretty well documented.

Comment: Thanks. this was really helpful. Decided to go with innerHTML